# Reading text file and checkboxes - PHP

Tags: php

Basically the code below reads in a text file and diplays it on the screen with checkboxes near each line. But now I want the user to be able to check any box and then display the selected results in a new PHP file - I thought I would have to read in the text file again and somehow refer it to the array, but I'm still stuck, so any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

### First php file

```
<?php
$filename = "file.txt";
$myarray = file($filename);
print "<form action='file2.php' method='post'>\n";
// get number of elements in array with count
$count = 0; // Foreach with counter is probably best here
foreach ($myarray as $line) {
  $count++; // increment the counter
  $par = getvalue($line);
  if ($par[1] <= 200) {
  // Note the [] after the input name
    print "<input type='checkbox' name='test[$count]' /> ";
    print $par[0]." ";
    print $par[1]." ";
    print $par[2]." ";
    print $par[3]."<br />\n";
  }
}
print "</form>";
```

### Second php file which should display the selected results

```
<?php
$filename = "file.txt";
$myarray = file($filename);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're over complicating the problem. You can just give the checkboxes a `value` atribute and read the array from the second page. Start with kus `print_r ($_POST)` on the second page to help you see what you have to work with.

Answer (score 1):

1) Think of format of your text file (could be something like `"Name1-Value 1-true\nName1-Value2-false"`) 
2) Learn [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) function 
3) Create a file with the default options 
4) Make a PHP script that opens the file, makes an array and prints the resoult - for example:

```
$handle = fopen('./file.txt','r');
$fileString = fread($handle,filesize('./file.txt'));
$handle = null; //Similar to unset($handle);
$array = explode($fileString, "\n");
echo '<form action="./script2.php">';
foreach ($array as $value) {
    $value = explode($value, "-");
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="'.$value[1].'" value="'.$value[2].'" checked="';
    if ($value[3]==true) {
        echo 'checked" /><br />';
    } else {
        echo '" /><br />';
    }
}
```

5) Make the second script that edits the file - for example:

```
if ($_GET == null;) {exit("He's dead, Jim!");}
$handle = fopen('./file.txt','r');
$fileString = fread($handle,filesize('./file.txt'));
    //Do something with the string :D
$handle = fopen('./file.txt','w');
fwrite($handle,$fileString);
```